# How to protect classes so they are not visible outside their package

Tags: java, class, protected

I'd like to be able to have two "protected" classes in my package. That is, I do not want files outside of my package to see them as visible - they will be for internal use within the package only.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Just leave out all keywords. The default visibility is [package-private](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), viewable within the package only.

e.g.:

```
// class Foo is public
public class Foo
{
    final private Bar bar = ...;
}

// class Bar is package-private
// (visible to all classes in the package, not visible outside the package)
class Bar
{
    ...;
}
```

Comment: Exactly. And the keyword protected means that it is only accessible by derived types

Comment: @Oskar: well, technically it looks like protected is visible by derived types *outside* the package, and *all* types inside the package.

Comment: surely classes outside Bar's package can't even see the Bar class, so they can't extend it. (What happens if a public class inside the package extends it though...?)

Comment: **Jakson S**, you are absolutely right, all the levels of access include each other in order. **private** allows access within the class, **package-private** (default) allows access within the package *and* within the class, **protected** allows access for child classes of other packages *and* within the package, finally **public** allows anything to have access and thus includes all other levels.
**Bennett McElwee**, protected members remain protected unless they are methods and they get overriden. But even then it would be overriden method that is allowed to be accessed.

Comment: If you don't want that any other class inherit, you can add `public final`, this allows you use the class but any class can  inherit