# How do I inherit a class in java, when the sub- and super-classes are in different packages

Tags: java

How do I inherit a class in java, when the sub- and super-classes are in    different packages

Comment: The same way as normal...?

Comment: A class doesn't care who or where its subclasses are (as long as its not final), it can be extended from anywhere. And you can extend any superclass as long as you are able to import it into your Java file where you extend the class.

Comment: Classes aren't aware of their children. As long as the child can see its parent, it can copy it, naturally.

Comment: @Kon: The class needs to be public, though, to be visible outside of the package.

Comment: @Thilo Or protected.

Comment: And not `final`.  And have an accessible constructor.

Comment: @Gendarme: Can a class be `protected`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869556/why-a-class-cannot-be-defined-as-protected?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Thilo They could, until you linked that post. Ugh... quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

To make a class visible outside of its package, declare it as `public`.

It can then be extended by classes in other packages (unless it is `final`, then it cannot be subclassed at all).

Just like with any use of classes outside of the current (and the `java`) package, you have to `import` it (or use the fully qualified name `my.other.package.ClassName`).

Answer (score 0):

Just like normal, use the `import` statement.

```
import some.folder.SuperClass

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    public SubClass(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `class SubClass extends some.folder.SuperClass` ever used, or is it too cluttery?

Comment: @Gendarme: It is too cluttery. You would use it only if you already have a class of the same name imported, such as `class Factory extends some.api.Factory`. But that should probably be avoided, too.

Comment: @Gendarme see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079823/importing-two-classes-with-same-name-how-to-handle