# Is there anything like an Internal class in Java?

Tags: java, class, access-modifiers, internal

In C# you can mark a class as `internal` so that it is only accessible from within the same package. Is there anything similar in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534733/java-protected-classes

Comment: @cmmi: Not really a duplicate, as the question is asked from an entirely different perspective. Same answer though.

Comment: Note that C# doesn't have `packages`- They have `namespaces` and `assemblies`. Packages are equivalent to namespaces. But Assemblies can be compared to JAR files in Java. The `internal` modifier makes a class only accessible within an assembly. As such it has nothing to do with namespaces or packages.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can create package-private classes by omitting the security modifier (public, private) from the class's declaration.

```
package com.sample;

class MyPackagePrivateClass
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: package is way better encapsulation than assembly

Comment: @hB0 : No way! How would you declare an "internal" helper class refereced in different packages? You simply cannot

Comment: What I meant is "a better way of software design" not more feature intensive (which MS always comes with)

Comment: While I agree a package is a definition far from namespace, programming several parts of a class library which may somewhat get weird, when classes have to call each other, but you don't want them to be accessible from outside that library AND then if you want to achieve this, you can't have these classes on separate packages.
Create a "Internal" package maybe, for classes used only by the own library maybe would be the safest way out.

Comment: Jar visible modifiers are not part of Java due to the nature jars are packaged. One can manually zip together already compiled classes (I had to do this on various occasions) - if "internal" was possible in java, that would allow one to easily access "internal" methods between classes which shouldn't have such visibility between them. A jar is not encapsulated in a strict manner as a dll is.

Comment: this is never like internal. internal in .Net talks about assembly-private NOT package-private. assembly is the product of your project  e.g. in C# a dll or exe file (in java it could be a jar file or in android apk).while package means a folder of class files !!!! java does not have any exact alternative to internal in C#. ill add an answer on this in a while.

Comment: @Lotfi : Referencing a package-internal class from outside the package defeats the purpose of it being internal to the package. In this regard, C#/.NET allows you to do that by transferring the visibility control away from the language to put it into the build system, which is IMO overall bad design. Unlike .NET assemblies, Jars do not alter the visibility and are truly orthogonal to the language, which is better design. Other languages like C++ and Eiffel also have explicitly declared visibility. C#'s internal is a crude tool.

Comment: @RaduSimionescu but that's pretty much what they did with Jigsaw Modules in Java 9, right ?

Answer (score 11):

Dropping the access modifier is similar to internal in C#.

**C#**

```
public class A
{
    public static int X;
    internal static int Y;
    private static int Z;
}
internal class B
{
    public static int X;
    internal static int Y;
    private static int Z;
    public class C
    {
        public static int X;
        internal static int Y;
        private static int Z;
    }
    private class D
    {
        public static int X;
        internal static int Y;
        private static int Z;
    }
}
```

**Java**

```
public class A
{
    public static int X;
    static int Y;
    private static int Z;
}
class B
{
    public static int X;
    static int Y;
    private static int Z;
    public class C
    {
        public static int X;
        static int Y;
        private static int Z;
    }
    private class D
    {
        public static int X;
        static int Y;
        private static int Z;
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/internal.html

Comment: That will work ONLY if the classes A,B,C,D are in the same package..
While in C# they just have to be in the same namespace,

Comment: @User1234 in the same assembly, not namespace.

Answer (score 11):

this Question has an accepted answer before but I think the answer is not fully clear for some one who is new in java coming from .Net.

Does java have some exact equivalent for internal modifier in C# ? short answer is NO (but you can achieve it some how and i will tell)!!

internal in C# is actually an "assembly-private" modifier. what is an assembly ?

Assembly is any product of your project (DLL or EXE in C# - equivalent in java can be a JAR file)

there is not any exact equivalent for internal in java. and what has been answered by Bryan Kyle and accepted is actually "package-private" (packages in java are equivalent for namespaces in C#) but some how what has been answered is the closest way to get the same result.

BUT how to get a fully same result as internal ? cant java have a solution for this ? the answer is YES.

it does have. but not with a modifier.
actually the best way to do this is a secret in packaging. the best practice of packing is to pack your classes by their relation not by their type.

many of us use packages named "Models" or "Presenters" and put all our models or presenters in them. while this is wrong. packages should be like "Book" containing "BookModel.java", "BookPresenter.java" , .....

this way you can make them package-private by omitting the modifier and have not any problem because you can access them in any class which need your package-private class because you have a good practice of packaging.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's called package private, you just define the class without any modifiers:

`package com.blah;
class Foo{ }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with C#, but in Java the default protection is that something is only accessible within the package:

public=accessible by anyone

private=accessible only within the current class

protected=accessible within the package or in any class that inherits from the current class

default=accessible within the package

I've always thought there should be a way to say "accessible by any class that inherits from the current class but not from anywhere else, this package or any other". But there isn't.

Comment: For your last comment, C# has "protected internal"

Comment: @projectshave nope its wrong. "protected internal" in C# can be accessed from allover your assembly too. actually to limit access of a class only to its subclasses in C# juse use "protected". while in java "protected" will be accessible from the same package plus to subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers (including the accepted one) talk about package-private. But that is far from the `internal` in C#.

A use case where you want only your classes in the same source root to access another class in the same source root and possibly at different packages (still in the same source root) while keeping it package-private is simply impossible in Java. If you use package-private then only the classes in the same package will have access to that resource. However, even the classes one level down in the same package (i.e. another package under that package) cannot access that class.

```
 a.b.c.A --> class A
 a.b.c.d.B --> public class B
```

Here `B` cannot access `A`. This forces you to unfortunately mark `A` as public.

The main difference is in the way C# or Java packs the compiled code. C# can mark them as internal (i.e. do not export the symbol from the assembly) but Java packs as `jar` files and the way a jar is imported is completely different.

---

So what is the practical solution:
Well first of all there is no **forcing** solution. One can use **javadocs** or **annotations** to mark a class as internal and discourage people from using it, stating that it is internal and it can be changed a lot, it is not part of the public API, just don't use it or you might get into trouble if you migrate to a new release...

I see two ways of doing this:

1. name your package as internal:

   ```
   package org.mycoollib.api;
   /** This class is part of my public API*/
   public class A{
     //...
   }

   package org.mycoollib.internal;
   /** This an internal class, don't use it or your code might not
    work in a new release */
   public class B{
     //...
   }
   ```

Some real life examples: `jdk.internal`, `io.netty.util.internal` and so on. When I see `internal` as a package name I simply avoid using the classes in that.

2. Use annotations to achieve the same goal as in `1`

   ```
   package org.mycoollib.api;
   /** This class is part of my public API*/
   public class A{
     //...
   }

   package org.mycoollib.internal;
   /** This an internal class, don't use it or your code might not
    work in a new release */
   @Internal
   public class B{
     //...
   }
   ```

Example: [android.annotation.SystemApi](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/libs/modules-utils/java/android/annotation/SystemApi.java;drc=master), [org.apache.poi.Internal](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/Internal.html)

There might even be libraries out there to provide such kind of annotations as well as maven plugins to warn people during their builds.

As a result, the solution is in the way of thinking: We simply warn people not to use it because we don't guarantee that its name and methods won't change. If they still insist on using it, then so be it. They know the risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class package local. This is the default scope for a class. i.e. where you have no access modifiers.

If you really want to put sometime you can create an annotation e.g. @package_local, I do this in places where I speicifc want it to be package local and didn't just leave it unspecificed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the default (package private) access level. Just leave out any access modifier on your class definition and you get what you want.